# Converting binary file to be submitted on UNIX

Tags: unix, binaryfiles

I just finished my program an dam having to submit it on the UNIX systems per my professors instructions. However, my program writes data to a file prog6.out which is a binary file. I need to submit this file along with the rest of my program files, however I get a message that it is a binary file and cannot be submitted. Is there any way I can work around this to submit my file on the UNIX system?

My program is supposed to read in input from a file named prog6.dat, perform some calculations on that data in order to create triangle objects, then write the final information to a file (prog6.out as per my professor's instructions). The contents of this file include 5 triangle objects each of which include the lengths of the three sides, the area, perimeter, color, and whether it is filled or not. I had asked in a previous question earlier about why when opening my prog6.out file all I see is random numbers, symbols, etc and was told that since it was a binary file, that was correct. If you need to see specific code let me know, there's just a lot of it and thought maybe this question could be answered without making y'all muddle through 4 classes worth of code ha.

Comment: Exactly how and where you need to transfer the file?

Comment: Why do you use a binary file?On which system (= operating system & processor)? Why can't you use a textual file? Edit your question to explain more what your file contains, and what is your program doing. Do you know about textual serialization formats like [JSON](http://json.org/)? Did you consider installing some Linux distribution on your own PC?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I am running Windows 8 (not sure about processor), however my class requires me to submit assignments on the UNIX system via the No Machine At Home remote log in tool.

Comment: Why you tell is which data the file contains? Is it important here? Why we don't have informations HOW you try to transfer the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using binary files is tricky on multiplatform projects. I'd go on writing and reading in binary in a predefined manner (endianness, bits per data type, ...), or as suggested use a textual representation.

If you just need to send a binary file, without guarantees about readability on the other side with your program, encode it with Base64.

Comment: How would I go about doing the encoding?

Comment: If you're asking about manually encoding the output file, you can use simple bit manipulation, for instance, using a 4-bytes array and put the components of a 32-bits integer into the array (or use htonl and similar functions). Be aware that you need to know the size of your types (use int32_t for instance). Floating points are trickier but the same approach can be adapted to them ( IEEE-754 provides sizes, and 32, 64 bits are the most common).